# Android studio not running .sh script with Jsch

Tags: bash, android-studio

Whenever I try to execute a sh script via Jsh nothing happens , however when I execute it through a normal ssh session it works fine , I haven't been able to get a single sh file to work/run regardless of the contents of the sh file.

I have tried

```
channelssh.setCommand("/home/exiatron00/Desktop/bash test.sh");
channelssh.setCommand("/home/exiatron00/Desktop/./test.sh");
channelssh.setCommand("/home/exiatron00/Desktop/test.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your command, so I would have to assume it's your setup.

Are you sure you're even logging into your server? I would check your `last` logs to make sure you are even connecting.

Are you on the same network as the machine you're attempting to connect to? If you aren't on wifi I would assume your machine is hidden behind a NAT.